# How to search using Table API

Tags: servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I want to figure out how to search a table's field for a keyword and return the rows that match. i.e. search for the word `apple` in the `description` field on a `post` table.

```
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/newyork-application-development/page/integrate/inbound-rest/concept/c_TableAPI.html#r_TableAPI-GET
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ServiceNow TABLE API to fetch results then you could the following on any column of any table. All you need to do is to use `sysparm_query` parameter with `CONTAINS` keyword on the column that you are trying to search.

**For example:**

I want to fetch all the incidents that contains `unable to connect` string in the descriptions.

```
https://myinstance.service-now.com/api/now/v2/table/incident?sysparm_query=descriptionCONTAINSunable+to+connect
```

It returned all the incidents records that contains `unable to connect` string in there descriptions.

[image]

Comment: You can mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question. So that it will help future readers.